# Find ghc version from executable

Tags: haskell, version, executable, ghc

I have an executable in my system which has been built via the GHC compiler. Is there a way to find which GHC version was used to build it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the `--info` flag into the RTS option to find that out:

```
$ tldr +RTS --info -RTS
 [("GHC RTS", "YES")
 ,("GHC version", "8.6.5")
 ,("RTS way", "rts_thr")
 ,("Build platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Build architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Build OS", "linux")
 ,("Build vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Host platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Host architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Host OS", "linux")
 ,("Host vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Target platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Target architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Target OS", "linux")
 ,("Target vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Word size", "64")
 ,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
 ,("Tables next to code", "YES")
 ]
```